# How can I say "passion for healing" in Latin?

Tags: motto, english-to-latin-translation

Have no idea here. I translated it on google but yeah it's not that trustworthy I know. Somehow I found out the word "*passio*","*ad*" and "*sanationem*".
We are going to use it as our school of medicine motto, so if you have any suggestion or idea please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question! Just a nuance: do you mean healing others or being healed?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest *cupiditas sanandi* or *cupiditas medendi*.

The noun *cupiditas* means a 'passionate desire, longing, yearning.' For example, in the *Pro Sulla* (40), Cicero says, *o di immortales...vos profecto animum meum tum conservandae patriae cupiditate incendistis*, 'Immortal gods...you inflamed my heart with a passion for preserving the state/Republic.'

For a slightly softened expression, one could use *studium*, 'eagerness,' 'enthusiasm' instead of *cupiditas*.

*Sanandi*/*medendi* is the genitive of the gerund. This is a so-called objective genitive, which is often found with nouns that describe emotions or actions to indicate the thing or person that the emotion/action is directed toward.

Answer (score -1):

"For healing" indicates a dative case, so it would be the nominative of *[passio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/passio#Latin)* with the dative of *[sanatio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sanatio)*:

> *passiō sānātiōnī*